# AWS Accounts and Bounded Contexts

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, cloud, domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

I am migrating a project from Azure to AWS. In Azure we used a subscription for each environment like "dev,test,prod" and resources groups to cluster resources that are part of a bounded context.

How would one organize this scenario in AWS? We started with AWS Organizations and organized the environments in different Organizational Unit. Within an OU would one rather create an Account for each bounded context or let all resources live in a single account and use resource groups instead?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would split down to at least one account per each environment within their respective organisational unit.

As time progresses you might look at splitting down further, such as accounts per application as well as accounts for specific functions such as centralisation of monitoring etc.

AWS have also published their list of best practices available [here](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/getting-started/best-practices/) if this helps with your decision.

Comment: Let's say within my project I have a couple of bounded contexts like "order, user mgmt, UI, user-billing, etc..". Would you put those contexts into a dedicated account each or just put them in one account and use resource groups instead?

Comment: If you're trying to have boundaries then yes they would there own separate accounts per environment. However, you might have an account for logging and then push all logs to that account.